# Манипулятор Mitsubishi RV-2AJ. Запрос координат по com порту с помощью Python и библиотеки pySerial

Tags: python, serial, com-порт

Решил поработать с манипулятором Mitsubishi RV-2AJ с помощью python на своем компьютере. Манипулятор управляется своим системным блоком (контроллером). От контроллера проводится обычный COM порт (RS-232) , и через USB переходник подключаю его к ноуту. Запрос данных осуществляется с помощью определенных 'стационарных' команд . Опробовал их запрашивать через программу "Advanced serial port monitor" , все работает хорошо, присылаются верный координаты. Когда дело дошло до сего кода, то ответа с робота не приходило ни в какой кодировке, в общем ноль реакции.

```
import serial

    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                        parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout = 2 )

    try:
        ser.isOpen()
        print('Serial port is open')
    except:
        print('Error')
        exit()

ser.write(b'1;-1;PPOSF')

print(ser.write(b'1;-1;PPOSF'))

    in_len = 0
    while in_len < 1:
        in_st = ser.read()
        in_len = len(in_st)
        print(in_st)

    print('Answer :', in_st)
```

Я новичок и в Python и в pySerial. Может кто встречался с такой проблемой или знает, как такое решить?

Comment: Правильно ли установлены параметры порта (сверить с рабочей программой)? Верен ли формат посылки - например, не нужно ли в конце посылать завершающий символ вроде \r, \n ? В цикле чтения не стоит ли сделать небольшие паузы? (Лучше, конечно, вообще асинхронно работать, если программа ещё чем-то занимается, и вообще есть такая возможность)

Comment: Спасибо за проявление интереса. Параметры порта вроде бы верны ( сверил с рабочей программой). Насчет остального не уверен. Завтра буду возле манипулятора и все попробую. Отпишусь.

Comment: В общем, все проверил, никаких изменений не поступило.

Comment: Можно поставить PortMon для 32-х разрядной или AccessPort для 64x-системы и проконтролировать настройки и обмен рабочей программы и своей

Comment: Все работает также ,как и в Advanced serial port monitor. Только программы эти чуть более костыльные .

Comment: Ну вот я взял этот код, исправил номер порта на свой, поставил на порт заглушку и принял назад b'1

Comment: Скорее всего, контроллер просто не понимает битовую информацию , возможно, нужно переводить в другую кодировку. Только как,если pySerial просит именно в bytes.

Comment: MBo,спасибо тебе большое. Решил еще раз  в конце команды добавить \r , получилось вот такое - ser.write(b'1;-1;PPOSF\r') и все заработало. Начал с HEX кодировки , продолжил с добавления \r после каждого символа. В итоге после нескольких рандомных вариантов пришел к твоему первому совету. Только до сих пор не пойму, зачем эти разделяющие символы нужны?

Comment: Оформил ответом, пояснение туда же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо выяснить подробности протокола - следует ли в конце посылать завершающий символ вроде `\r, \n`

Они используются для упрощения протокола обмена - текстовая команда заканчивается переводом строки `LF=\n=10`, возвратом каретки `CR=\r=13` или их комбинацией. Приемное устройство получило стоп-символ - строка принята полностью, можно обрабатывать