# Как получить данные с COM-порта на Python?

Tags: python, windows, администрирование

есть промышленные весы, передающие данные на COM-порт, как их принять используя `MSCOMM32.OSX`?

P.S. Пробовал сделать это с помощью пакета pyserial, но смог считать данные только с com-порта к которому подключена мышь, как выяснилось, это происходит потому что pyserial работает с com портом как с файлом.

Comment: А что с другими портами? Гляньте пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827288

Comment: @MBo Да, написал как в примере который вы скинули, но таким образом удалось прочитать только с мышки данные

Comment: Что происходит при работе с другими портами?