# Не могу прочитать ответ с COM-порта (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, com-порт, com-port

Не могу прочитать ответ с COM-порта.
В основном при попытке чтения читает 0 байт, либо очень редко выдает всякий мусор.
С time.sleep() и timeout игрался, не помогает.
На чистом C все получается, а вот на Python как-то не выходит.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Запись в COM-порт:

```
        buf = bytearray([0, 0, 0, 0])
        buf[0] = COM_WRITE
        buf[1] = value
        buf[2] = value + 1
        buf[3] = (2 * buf[1] + buf[0] + 1) & 0xFF
```

Чтение из COM-порта:

```
        raw = bytearray([0, 0, 0, 0])
        raw = ser.read(4)
```

После чего проверяю длину:

```
        if  len(raw) == 4:
```

Пишет, что длина = 0

Вот код сишной проги:

```
int COM_Read(int fd, unsigned char value) {
unsigned char buf[4];
int len, rc;
struct timespec tt = {0, 250000000};

// Читаем ответ
rc = 0;
rpt:
len = read(fd, buf, 4);
if (len == 0) {
    // Аттенюатор не упел ответить - ждём
    nanosleep(&tt, NULL);
    goto rpt;
}
...
```

Comment: Параметры порта верно настроены? Что значит мусор?  Вот некий питоновский пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827288

Comment: Параметры настроены, вроде, верно
По крайней мере при передаче команды прибор выполняет ее верно.

                  ser = serial.Serial(self.com_port_name)
                  ser.baudrate = 57600
                  ser.timeout = 1
                  ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
                  ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
                  ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
                  ser.xonxoff=False
                  ser.rtscts=False
                  ser.dsrdtr=False

Comment: Под мусором имею ввиду непонятные значения байтов.

Comment: Может быть, дело в интерпретации принятых значений? Что должно быть, как ведётся контроль?

Comment: Должны быть приняты 4 байта, первый из которых различный с отправленным, а остальные три - идентичны. Но дело в том, что он читает 0 байт.

Comment: А цикл ожидания сделан?

Comment: Если чтение вернуло 0, то такой цикл ожидания у меня присутствует:
            while len(raw) == 0:
                time.sleep(0.25)
                raw = ser.read(4)

Comment: https://ideone.com/2eJkQa При наличии заглушки читает обратно то, что послано в порт.  При ser.read(1) собирает посылку по байту

Comment: Все равно печатает нулевые строки байт.

Comment: Если есть возможность, лучше проконтролировать обмен с помощью PortMon для 32-х разрядной или AccessPort для 64x-системы. И любую терминальную программу (или штатную, если есть к прибору) попробовать вместо своей.